# PyAIML failing with use of "secure" predicate

Tags: aiml

I've just started playing with PyAIML. My notes are at http://webseitz.fluxent.com/wiki/AIML.

I'm trying to use a starting AIML [file](https://github.com/BillSeitz/pyAIML/blob/master/fatbot.aiml) that loads a whole directory of AIML files. But getting the `You are not permitted to load AIML sets` response. Even after adding `k.setBotPredicate("secure", "yes")` in the [code](https://github.com/BillSeitz/pyAIML/blob/master/fatbot.py).

What am I missing?